# Rails how to query nested association returning all nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :invoice
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :receipt
end

class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

**I want to return all of the receipts for all of the orders that a user has.**

If the relationship was one to one the whole way down it would be straightforward:

```
user = User.find(...)

user.order.invoice.receipt
```

Because there are many orders, I find myself wanting to map and flatten. I don't want to do that. I can't seem to find sources that help me truly grok this concept. Do I need to define a `through` relationship? do I need to use `.joins`?

**How can I return the receipt of an invoice of all orders owned by a specific user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Receipt.joins(invoice: { order: :user }).where(users: { id: user_id })
```

Yes, you need to use joins to generate a proper query (join all tables along the way and add your user restriction).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using a subquery.

```
users = User.where(id: user_id)
orders = Order.where(user_id: users)
invoices = Invoice.where(order_id: orders)
receipts = Receipt.where(invoice_id: invoices)
```

The above should execute a single query when `receipts` is loaded. When copied into the terminal suffix the lines with `;nil` to prevent the *inspect* method (which is used to show the terminal return value) to load the collections.

---

**Note:** Normally you would need to specify the attribute to select. However the *id* attribute (primary key) is selected implicitly by not selecting an attribute.

```
orders = Order.where(user_id: users)
# is the same as
orders = Order.where(user_id: users.select(:id))
```

Keep this in mind when you need to create a subquery based on another attribute than the *id*. For example when changing the subquery direction.

```
users = User.where(id: orders.select(:user_id))
```

Comment: You could even leave out the first line and provide the `user_id` straight to the orders *where* constraint. `orders = Order.where(user_id: user_id)`